# Shared folder of pc on Mobile

Tags: android, lan, ping, subnet, tethering

I have following setup
Galaxy on8 with Wi-Fi hotspot on : 192.168.43.1

Xolo a500 connected to Wi-Fi hotspot :192.168.43.23

And also same  xolo a500 connected to pc (mint linux) via usb cable with usb tethering ..
So for that connection 
xolo a500: 192.168.42.1
Pc:              192.168.42.12

I can access shared folder of pc on xolo a500  via usb connection.
But I can't access the same on galaxy on8.
However if turn on some server app on galaxy on8 and put its ip address on pc I can view that servers interface ..
Or in different word 
I can ping galaxy on8 from pc
I can ping xolo a500 with both address.
But I can't ping pc from galaxy on8.

Pc and galaxy on8 are on different subnet..and I can't merge these subnet..

This happens with all the android device 
They have 192.168.43.* with Wi-Fi interface.
And 192.168.42.* with usb interface..

These details are same for win7 on same pc.

My question is this 
If I can ping galaxy on 8 from pc then why can't I do vice versa ?

And

how I can view shared folder of pc on Galaxy on8 on this setup..?

(I don't want to root my Galaxy on8,but xolo a500 is rooted,and I can interchange position of both device on this setup if that helps!!!!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run `iptables -L` in Xolo.

if You find something like this,

Chain FORWARD policy DROP

then it is clear that Xolo a500 is not forwarding packets coming from Wifi Network To USB Network.
you need to change FORWARD policy to ACCEPT in iptables of xolo
to do so instead of typing command ,
install AFWall+ app on rooted xolo,
open it and grant superuser permission to it,
tick WiFi and Lan checkbox of (tethering) - DHCP + DNS services from the list,
then option -> Apply 
then option -> Enable Firewall

done..

one other thing ,
if ping from On8 to PC is not working then try to add route from  Galaxy on8 to PC via Xolo A500 in Galaxy on8 by this command

```
ip route add 192.168.42.0/24 via 192.168.43.23 dev wlan0
```

if you can't add route in On8 (your Galaxy on9 is NOT rooted)
then make small change on above setup you provided.
1 swicth on hotspot of xolo a500 
2 connect galaxy on8 to xolo a500
and everything else remains untouched

now a default route to xolo a500 will be added in Galaxy on8.

done...

Answer (score 0):

The could be an issue with `netmask`. Can you check  Gateway, DNS and other details  using the codes from terminal

```
ip addr show
```

and,

```
ip route show
```

Check if they correspond with other two, otherwise the galaxy phone is likely to be in a different subnet.

Comment: Galaxy is on 192.168.43.* network....

Comment: And pc is on 192.168.42.* network

Comment: OK these are IP address, I meant subnet. Usually a single subnet corresponds to a set of IP address and if your connections are in the same subnet you can ean easily connect since their leased IP are linked e.g 255.255.255.0 gives IP ranges 192.168.43.xxx (default for android-24 bit prefix) while the other 32bit 255.255.255.255 prefixes usually give 10.1.2.xxx.xxx range

Comment: It could be that the both the Xolo and PC are in different subnets with galaxy phone.. Now if you connect the Xolo to Wi-Fi hotspot it's new IP address belongs to the new subnet of galaxy with ranges 192.168.43.xxx **and no longer 192.168.42.xx as before** with Linux PC as they belong to 192.168.42.xxx range via USB. This can be the only explanation. If you want **all of them in one subnet** then make them connect through a single access point i.e Wi-Fi hotspot, that way they have same network prefix or netmask

Comment: Hi first, in both connection ,subnet are 255.255.255.0

Comment: And if i connect xolo to wifi hotspot ,it is assigned 192.168.43.* address by galaxy phone....

Comment: And then if i connect xolo to pc (while keeping wifi connection) it assigns 192.168.42.* to pc AND XOLO ITSELF BECOMES 192.168.42.1...

Comment: So in short xolo has TWO ip address (both can be pinged from pc)

Comment: I hope you will understand this.....